# New tradingview (pinescript) translation error/structurelookback

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, tradingview-api

so I'm trying to teach myself pinescript so that I can execute trades automatically using tradingview. I'm new to pine script (I know a little python) and am learning from a youtuber before I properly start doing it on my own.

```
`study("Autoview Trailing Stop", overlay=true)

// Get user input
trailType = input(title="Trail Type", type=input(string), defval="Long", options=["Long",       "Short"]))
structurelookback = input(title="Lookback", type=input(integer), defval=7)
atrLength = input(title="ATR Length", type=input(integer), defval=14)
//barIndex = input(title="", type =, defval=)
//trailType = input(title="", type =, defval=)

plot(bar_index)
```

It keeps throwing out " Script could not be translated from: ["Long","Short"])|E|
|B|structurelookback "`
Any help would be greatly appreciated

My current code is a complete copy of his in the video bar the input, he used input. rather than input(), I have tried both. The script did not recognise input. so I switched it to input() - must be that we are on v5 now. Although, I am likely wrong on that front too.

Answer (score 0):

`type=input(string)` this is wrong.

`type` expects a `const string`. You are calling the `input` function and passing it as `type`.

You should be passing `input.string` instead. Also, there is one extra `)` in that statement.

```
trailType = input(title="Trail Type", type=input.string, defval="Long", options=["Long",       "Short"])
```